# Tables are not creating with hook_schema

Tags: database

I need to create a module to save data of term page visits.

```
<?php

function term_count_schema() {
  $schema['term_search'] = array(
  'description' => 'Stores timestamp range..',
'fields' => array(
  'tid' => array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'size' => 'tiny',
    'description' => 'Taxonomy ID.',
   ),
  'vid' => array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'size' => 'tiny',
    'description' => 'Vocabulary ID.',
    ),
  'timestamp' => array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'description' => 'UNIX timestamp.',
   ),
 ),
 'primary key' => array('tid'),

  );

  $schema['term_count'] = array(
'description' => 'Total views.',
'fields' => array(
  'tid' => array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'size' => 'tiny',
    'description' => 'Taxonomay ID.',
  ),
  'vid' => array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'size' => 'tiny',
    'description' => 'Vocabulary ID.',
  ),
  'totalviews' => array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'size' => 'tiny',
    'description' => 'Total number of views which increments on every page load.',
  ),
),
'primary key' => array('tid'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

This is not creating tables term_search & term_count ind DB. Any thing wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains install and update functions for Views.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function mid_components_install(){

}

/**
 * Implements hook_schema().
 *
 */
function mid_components_schema(){
    $schemas = array();
    $schemas['mid_components'] = array(
        'description' => 'The mid_components data.',
        'fields' => array(
            'cid' => array(
                'description' => 'Primary key',
                'type' => 'serial',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
            'title' => array(
                'description' => 'Human readable name of the component.',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 255,
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
            'machine_name' => array(
                'description' => 'Unique machine name of the component',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 255,
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
            'description' => array(
                'description' => 'Description of the component.',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 255,
                'not null' => FALSE,
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'description' => 'A serialized array of options for this display; it contains options that are generally only pertinent to that component.',
                'type' => 'blob',
                'size' => 'big',
                'not null' => FALSE,
            ),
            'status' => array(
                'description' => 'Status of the component',
                'type' => 'int',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => 0,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
            ),
            'created' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the item is created',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => 0,
            ),
            'changed' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the item is modified.',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => 0,
            ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('cid'),
        'unique key' => array('machine_name' => array('machine_name')),
    );
    return $schemas;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function mid_components_uninstall(){

}
```

Follow this method. And Make sure after doing any chnagings to your .install file, uninstall your module and reinstall it again.

Comment: Thanks Suagndh Khanna. It works for single table. I need one more table in DB. How i can create one more table within one hook_schema()

Comment: You can have multiple schemas under single hook_schema. For better understanding try exploring Drupal contrib modules - .install file.